# How to use MediaUploader class to send attachment around 15 MB

Tags: gmail-api

Can anyone please help me understand how I can use MediaUploader class while sending an email with attachment of around 15 MB?

Currently I am able to send email with attachments upto 950 KB but not more than that.

URL being used is - url:https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/user@xyz.com/messages/send

My code looks something like this,

.......

```
DataReader* reader = NewManagedInMemoryDataReader(&MsgData);
DataReader* encoder = codec->NewManagedEncodingReader(reader, NULL, &status);
encoder->ReadToString(/*RawMessage.length()*/kint64max, &EncodedPayload);

Message* message = Message::New();
message->set_raw(EncodedPayload);

OAuth2Credential* credential_ = GetUserCredential(email);

std::unique_ptr<UsersResource_MessagesResource_SendMethod> method(service_->get_users().get_messages().NewSendMethod                                                                                (credential_, email.c_str(), message, "", NULL));

method->ExecuteAndParseResponse(message)
```

......

Below is log extract on error,

```
I0904 12:06:42.522728 17834 client_service.cc:100] Prepared url:https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/user%40xyz.com/messages/send
I0904 12:06:42.524838 17834 http_request.cc:1083] Adding builtin headers
I0904 12:06:42.524919 17834 http_request.cc:285] set_state_code=2 on 0xf7212d88
I0904 12:06:42.524960 17834 http_request.cc:609] DoExecute using transport:Curl
I0904 12:06:42.525488 17834 curl_http_transport.cc:335] Setting timeout to ms=1234567
I0904 12:06:44.138020 17834 curl_http_transport.cc:385] Got http_code=413 for POST url=https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/user%40xyz.com/messages/send
I0904 12:06:44.150180 17834 http_transport.cc:223] No configured error handler for http_code=413
I0904 12:06:44.150480 17834 http_request.cc:768] Finished 0xf7212d88
I0904 12:06:44.150554 17834 http_request.cc:285] set_state_code=3 on 0xf7212d88
I0904 12:06:44.150590 17834 http_request.cc:320] Signal 0xf7212d88
```

How do we use resumable upload?
As in do we have to use this method " GmailService::UsersResource::DraftsResource::NewSendMethod(client::AuthorizationCredential* *credential*, const StringPiece& user_id, const Draft* *metadata*, const StringPiece& _media_content_type_, client::DataReader* _media_content_reader_)" ?

Thanks,
Harshal

Comment: Please post the code on how you are sending email with attachment upto 950 KB. what error are you getting with larger files? If its more than 5MB, you should go with Resumable upload https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads#simple